# Sitecore Web Form for Marketers - create a cookie

Tags: cookies, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

This is a two part question.
Using Web Forms for Marketers 2.3:
Is it possible to have a cookie be created on successful submission?
Without actually exporting the ascx file, would like to keep it in Sitecore.

Second question, would it be better to have a content editor choose which item has the form or would it be better/easier to have a dropdown to pick which form is needed and then have the code determine which form to show.

Thank for any insight!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the First question,

If you have Sitecore DMS, on a successful submission there is an event, and a Goal maybe you can use that, insteed of a cookie. 
See https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/personalization/walkthrough%20personalizing%20components for using it with personalization rules the picturs are for Sitecore 8 but basically the same for Sitecore 6.5+

Programmatically you can use the Analytics API, see https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/engagement_analytics_api_cookbook_sc65-a4.pdf for Sitecore 6. The API has changed considerably with Sitecore 7.5.

An alternative is to set the cookie on the Success page.
you can have a Success page, or a Success message in WFFM. for a message use something like this:

```
Thanks <script>document.cookie="formsuccess=ok";</script>
```

Comment: Is there a property or a method that returns true or false if the submission was successful?

Comment: With Sitecore 6 DMS? With the Sitecore rules engine, you can easily check on a goal triggered during the current visit, (personalization) than you have a true or false and can you display a other component or hide/show the component.

Comment: Just to make sure i'm not crazy, I can use the rule engine and then be able to reference on Submission postback using Sitecore.Form.Core to give me if it's true or false. Do you know which method or property would that be?

Comment: I was thinking more of making use of personalization in the "page editor" or using the Sitecore Analytics API, since you're on an older version and the API has already changed you know upgrade issues when you are directly using the Analytics API.